# When send() returns EWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN, is it possible for it to have written partial bytes?

Tags: linux, sockets

When `send()` returns `EWOULDBLOCK`/`EAGAIN`, is it possible for it to have written partial bytes? Or is it atomic behaviour ... either it wrote all the bytes or nothing at all?

Is it possible for `send()` to write partial bytes (not complete) and return success?

Comment: I don't think so because OS generally either allow all the write either return would block. But in theory this could happen in TCP.

Comment: It depends on the type of socket. A datagram socket is all or nothing, a stream socket will write as much as it can.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your comment

Answer (score 0):

It's possible for `send()` to write partial data in a stream socket. However, it won't set `errno` to `EWOULDBLOCK`/`EAGAIN` in that case.

`errno` is only set when `send()` returns `-1`, which means that nothing was written at all. It will be `EWOULDBLOCK`/`EAGAIN` if the reason for not writing is because there's no buffer space available.

`send()` returns the number of bytes that were written. If it writes partial data, the return value will be less than the number of bytes requested.

Answer (score 0):

If `send()` returns < 0, whether that be for `EWOULDBLOCK`/`EAGAIN` or any other error, then no bytes were accepted <sup>1</sup> for sending at all.  If any bytes were accepted, the return value of `send()` would be > 0 to report the actual number of bytes.

<sup>1: I say *accepted* because the actual tranmission is done in the background at the kernel's leisure. `send()` merely places bytes into the socket's outbound buffer for the kernel to transmit at a later time.</sup>

Whether or not a partial send is possible depends on the socket type.

A stream-based socket, like for TCP, allows partial sends, yes.  It will take as many bytes as it can, and return how many bytes were actually taken, if no error occurs.

A datagram socket, like for UDP, does not allow partial sends, no.  It is all or nothing.